# comparing file in incrementally numbered directories using bash

Tags: bash

I have created a subdir in `test` dir for each of the test cases.

```
#ls test/
test1   test2   test3   test4   test5
```

Each subdir contains `expected.txt` & `actual.txt` files. I am trying validate that contents in both of those files are identical using bash `diff` command.
Since there will tens of such test cases, I am iterating over the subdirectories as they are named with increasing number as suffix. 
However, getting following error on `while` statement:

```
num=1
while [[ -f ./test/test${num} ]] ; do
    DIFF=$(diff test/test${num}/actual.txt test/test${num}/expected.txt)

    if [ "$DIFF" != "" ]
    then
        echo "Test Case ${num} ...Failed"
    else
        echo "Test Case ${num} ...Passed"
    fi

    num++
done
```

**Error**

while [[ -f ./test/test ]] ; do

/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

If there better way of achieving what I am trying to do, that will be a learning too.

Comment: By sub directory do you mean test1 , test2 ... are all directories?

Comment: If so use -e. -f is only for regular files

Answer (score 0):

You get an syntax error in your script, because you use bash extension `[[` and run your script using `/bin/sh`. Either run your script under bash or replace the `[[` with a single `[`.

You script makes no sense:

- `[[ -f` - checks if `./test/test${num}` is a *file*. So, if it is a file, the while body will execute. Then you compare `./test/test${num}/actual.txt` file. But if `./test/test${num}` is a file it is not a directory, so there can't be any `./test/test${num}/anything` because it's a file. Most probably you meant to use `-d`.
- `diff` is for nice looking output in terminal. Use `cmp` to compare files in scripts.

I guess your script could look like this:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -regex './test/test[0-9]+' |
while read -r dir; do
   if cmp "$dir"/actual.txt "$dir"/expected.txt; then
       echo "Test case $dir Failed"
   else
       echo "Test case $dir Passed"
   fi
done
```

Comment: What is that `-r` before `read`? Seems wrong. Also, why not just `for dir in ./test/*; do ...`?

Comment: Because `./test/*` will also pick up `./test/abc` and `./test/anything`. Och, there is a typo, `-r` should be after `read`, thanks.  `-r` is for properly interpreting backslash characters, it's uneeded here as there can't be any backslash characters, but I write it because I am used to. See [how to read a stream line by line greg wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [posix read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) and ex [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)